# button-form alignment with CSS3 and cross browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser, css, alignment, padding

I've been trying to get a textfield and button to align flush with each other, I have tried two methods, using height, as well as just padding, but when one works for one browser, it doesn't work for the other, and vise versa.

Does anyone know of how to fix this problem? a screenshot is present below.

http://img291.imageshack.us/i/75462612.png/

The screenshot is from using the code below - and when I use padding instead of height, firefox looks fine, but chrome is unaligned..

```
.buttons {
font-family:arial;
font-size:18px;
height:38px;
margin-left:-1px;
border:1px solid #b4b4b4;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cb43b3), to(#a5108b));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cb43b3,  #a5108b);
-moz-border-top-right-radius:5px;
border-top-right-radius:5px;
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
color:#fff;
}
.buttons:hover {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#a5108b), to(#cb43b3));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a5108b,  #cb43b3);
}
.textarea {
border:1px solid #b4b4b4;
-moz-border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-top-left-radius:5px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf;
padding:7px;
font-family:arial;
font-size:18px;
color:#7e7e7e;
width:300px;
}
```

Just assume this has no other code except the body tags..as even trying with just body tags this problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified it a bit...

```
.buttons { font-family:arial; font-size:18px; height:40px; border:1px solid #b4b4b4; background:
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cb43b3), to(#a5108b)); background:
-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cb43b3,  #a5108b);
-moz-border-top-right-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px; color:#fff; float: left; display: block; } .buttons:hover { background:
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#a5108b), to(#cb43b3)); background:
-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a5108b,  #cb43b3); } .textarea { border:1px solid #b4b4b4;
-moz-border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-left-radius:5px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf; box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf; box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf; padding: 0px 7px; font-family:arial; font-size:18px; color:#7e7e7e; width:300px; height: 38px; line-height: 38px; float: left; display: block; margin-right: 2px; }
```